# Hapi.js 17.*: Static content catch all for directory handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm using Inert with Hapi.js and I have a simple directory handler setup that serves a React App:

```
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
      directory: {
        path: '.',
        redirectToSlash: true,
        index: true,
      },
    },
  }
```

This works fine when visiting http://localhost:8080. When I add /anything, I get a 404.

How can I get all requests to redirect to the path that's defined? I've read the Inert documentation and tried multiple ideas from the Hapi.js API docs to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I used the `onPreResponse` lifecycle hook for Hapi to always send my `index.html` when the response is 404

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', (req, h) => {
  const { response } = req;
  if (response.isBoom && response.output.statusCode === 404) {
    return h.file('index.html');
  }
  return h.continue;
});
```

This way it always falls back to my ui, which allows react-router to handle the non-api routes. You can read more about Hapi's lifecycles in [the docs.](https://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle)

Comment: Thanks!  I'm new to HapiJs and this post helped me to debug the actual issue. Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

this is my setup for react serving and working without a problem.

Route config:

```
{
                method: 'GET',
                path: '/{param*}',
                config: Controller.dashboard
            },
```

Controller:

```
exports.dashboard = {
    auth: false,
    description: 'ui build request handler',
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        return h.file(config.get('uiBuildPath') + 'index.html', {confine: false});
    }
};
```

`config.get('uiBuildPath')` is returning the path of my react app build directory in the server. Just this 
I put route config to end of my routing definitions, here is exact order. Make sure to put this definition to end

```
server.route([
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/login',
        options: Controller.login
    },        
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/logout',
        options: Controller.logout
    },
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        config: Controller.dashboard
    },
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',
        config: Controller.dashboard
    },
]);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. You hare setting up Hapi.js routes for each route within your React app. This is why I am trying to get a catch all as I'm using React Router, which handles all routing, including a 404 page. I started adding routes, as well as a generator to parse an array, but then I lost my 404 handling from within the SPA. I also tried server ext events https://hapijs.com/api/17.5.2#-serverextevents but this just through up blank white page.

Comment: Hi, first two routes actually returns their own views they aren't handling any react related content. Last two (actually only last one) handles all requests. But I should probably mentioned earlier that I'm using react-router so none of my route changes hit to my server. I just wanted to give an example. If it's not worked sorry for that.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but using `confine: false` like that is dangerous. Using the code provided here is a serious security risk. Using the `file` handler instead of the `directory` handler should solve the 404 problems, though.

Comment: I got it, but i am giving it to exact directory path not a relative one. If you know what your doing I don't think this is a security issue, it's a different consideration of the problem. Ahh, down voting is easy of course.